# When you make edits to a file within a project using AnkhSVN, can this be reflected at the project level?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

When I make edits to file, TortoiseSVN will show an indication on the folder that file belongs to that there are changes pending to child items.  AnkhSVN only shows (red tick) changes to a project when files are added/removed (because the actual content of the project file in this case has changed)

Can you make ankh give any indication at the project level that child items have been edited?

Comment: No, you can't. Ankh only shows an indication on modified files, whereas TSVN can traverse folders recursively and mark those with changed files within.

Comment: @Igor care to add that as an answer? :)

Comment: I added the answer trying to be a bit more constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Ankh only shows an indication on modified files, whereas TortoiseSVN can traverse folders recursively and mark those with changed files within them.

If you desperately need this feature, you can try out [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) plugin. It tries to mimic TortoiseSVN behaviour as close as possible. In fact, it uses TSVN dialogs for operations such as Commit or Update, for instance. When you modify a file within a project, it highlights the file, the project this file belongs to, as well as the solution node in the Solution Explorer.

Unfortunately, it's not free (US $49 per seat), but IMO it is worth its price.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to see what changed globally in AnkhSVN is the 'Pending Changes' toolwindow. This shows you all interesting files in a single view and allows you to operate on them easily.

You can open the toolwindow via View->Pending Changes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
Right Click the File -> Subversion -> Lock
This places a lock on the file so that others cannot edit it. 
When you commit, it should unlock the file.

If it does not, Follow the same steps and select Unlock.

Edit: I use AnkhSVN for my svn but it's just me that uses it.  If a corporate environment I mainly use TFS which does the same thing (lock/unlock) but it does not allow others to check out.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the solution in Visual Studio and selecting "View Solution History" ? This would show changes in the solution.

Comment: Yes, View solution history works as expected, but that does not answer the question